# How to fix the curl error while trying to PUT the data into server

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am trying to send the log file to my server but I am getting error while running the code.

This is for RPI running Raspbian Buster Lite

```
#!/bin/sh

ping -q -c5 google.com > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
echo "$(date) - Connected" >> /home/weewx/internet-connection-status.log

statuslog=$(cat /home/weewx/internet-connection-status.log)

curl -d {$statuslog} -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT  [server url here]

if [ $? -eq 200 ]
then
 truncate -s 0 /home/weewx/internet-connection-status.log
fi

else
  echo "$(date) - Not Connected" >> /home/weewx/internet-connection-status.log
fi
```

> curl: option -: is unknown   curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl
>   --manual' for more information

Comment: Quote the `$statuslog` variable in the `curl` command.

Comment: curl -d {$statuslog} -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT http://rmt.mountainhazelnuts.com/AWS/Api/InternetConnectionLog/SendAwsConnectionData

Comment: I don't understand your comment. That command looks the same as your original.

Comment: It should be `curl -d "{$statuslog}" ...`

Comment: @Barmar It worked, Thank you for the help. Have a great day